# Workout line segment inside expanding circle

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

I have what is probably a fairly basic math problem for a game I'm creating. On each frame I need to work out how much a sub segment of a line passing though a circle will expand when the circle expands by DR.

[image: Problem Diagram]

I think I've worked out a solution but I want to confirm that this is the best way of doing it. Assuming I already know what the section of the line is in the circle, I can find the closest point on the line to the center of the circle and make a line to the center which should make a right angle. Knowing the length of this line I can then use Pythagorean theorem to solve for the segment going from the intersection of the line to the radius of the new circle. If I'm solving for DX the equation would be something like:

$$
DX = \sqrt{(R + DR)^2 - L^2} - X
$$

Is there a better way to do this? What I really need to know is the vector that represents DX compered to DR.